# How do I reschedule a visa appointment?

Tags: visas, usa

How it happened:

I scheduled an appointment confirmation for 3rd June, 2015 before I completed visa application DS-160 online.

Observation at the Embassy-Appointment Confirmation Barcode Number is different from Visa Application Barcode Number. The interview was canceled and asked to reschedule another appointment.

How do I reschedule another appointment?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to go online to [USA Travel Docs](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/) pick a country where you have an appointment and for the particular type of visa application go to "Schedule Appointment", which will have the links to schedule one or reschedule one.